# Add Model Validation {Rails}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have two model association as follows:
Survey_question and survey_answer.

**Survey_question Model**

```
class SurveyAnswer < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :survey_question

validates_presence_of :answer_content, if: "answer_type!=Radio Button"
end
```

**Survey_question Model**

```
class SurveyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :survey

has_many :survey_answers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_answers, allow_destroy: true

has_many :survey_responses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_responses

validates :question_content, presence: true
validates :answer_type, presence:  true
end
```

I just to validate presence of survey_answer's answer_content when survey_question's answer_type is "Radio Button" ? how can I achieve this ??
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are looking for an `if` or `unless` based on using `!=` in your example, but try the following:

`validates_presence_of :answer_content, if: ->(answer) { answer.survey_question.answer_type == 'Radio Button' }`

Comment: I have answer_type in survey_question model and want to validate presence answer_content from survey_answer only if I have answer_type value i.e. radio button

Comment: So... Yes, I think this answers your question? Can you confirm whether it solves your problem? If yes, and you are happy with the solution, mark the answer as correct.

Comment: no it doesn't. can you tell me what does answer stands for ?

Comment: By using the above validation your `SurveyAnswer` will only validate the presence of `answer_content` when the related `SurveyQuestion` answer type is Radio Button. If you want to only validate the presence of `answer_content` when the type is _not_ 'Radio Button' then replace the `if` with `unless`.